# My table does not get body from css class

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

My task is streightforward: I have a table which is going to be filled with JQuery Template and I cannot get the css style on it.

To tell you all the naked truth, I took the css classes ready from here:

http://www.csstablegenerator.com/?table_id=68

I copypasted the following class from that site:

```
.CSSTableGenerator {
margin:0px;padding:0px;
width:100%;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
border:1px solid #000000;

-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
border-top-right-radius:0px;

-moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
border-top-left-radius:0px;
}
```

**It's a long part of css file, I copied it all the the end of my site.css. For some reasons I cannot copy it to my question here**

OK, here is my table:

```
<div class="CSSTableGenerator">
<table id="main car table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Car Id
            </th>
            <th>
                License Plate Number
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="addCarHere"></tbody>
</table>
```

OK... I add rows to the table using this...

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var listOfCars = [];
        var currenCar = null;
        $.getJSON("api/Car/GetAll", function (result) {
            listOfCars = result;
            alert(listOfCars.length)
            for (var num = 0; num <= listOfCars.length-1; num++) {
                $("#carRow").tmpl(listOfCars[num]).appendTo($("#addCarHere"))
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

...and nothing happens. like there is no additional lines in css at all!!

update: here I am implementing the Jquery Template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="carRow" class="CSSTableGenerator">
<tr data-carid="${ID}">
    <td>${ID}</td>
    <td class="licensePlateNumber">${LicensePlateNumber}</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using this jQuery Template plugin: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jquery-tmpl

Modify your code to compile your html template like so:

```
var markup = $('#carRow').html(); 
$.template( "rowTemplate", markup );
$.tmpl("rowTemplate",listOfCars[num]).appendTo($("#addCarHere"));
```

If that doesn't work for you, I recommend creating a jsfiddle for SO to help you with.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement that Jquery Template Plugin. But I have instead of $tmpl another code: <script type="text/template" id="carRow" class="CSSTableGenerator">
    <tr data-carid="${ID}">
        <td>${ID}</td>
        <td class="licensePlateNumber">${LicensePlateNumber}</td>

    </tr>
</script>